# find Column wise distinct count in SQL . Can anyone explain in detail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is one table:-

```sql
CREATE TABLE country_test2 (c1 varchar(20), c2 varchar(20), c3 varchar(20),c4 varchar(20))

INSERT INTO country_test2 VALUES ('india','us','china','uk')
INSERT INTO country_test2 VALUES ('india','india','china','uk')
INSERT INTO country_test2 VALUES ('india','china','china','uk')
INSERT INTO country_test2 VALUES ('us','us','us','uk')
```

How to find column wise distinct count in sql server.
I do have Answer with me, but unable to understand the logic.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM country_test2 t
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vp)
                  FROM (VALUES (t.c1),
                               (t.c2),
                               (t.c3),
                               (t.c4)) v(vp)) p(DistinctCount);
```

Comment: *"I do have Answer with me, but unable to understand the logic."* If you have a solution why haven't you included it and explained what about it confuses you?

Comment: Sure, here is the answer.    Answer:- But unable to understand the below logic,  Any help is super appreciated!! SELECT *
FROM country_test2 t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vp)
   FROM (VALUES (t.c1), (t.c2), (t.c3), (t.c4)) v (vp)
) p (DistinctCount)

Comment: *"can you please reply?"*... It's been 14 minutes, and the users here are under no obligation to drop everything to answer your questions; we're volunteers not paid consultants.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Thank you for the Url. But generally speaking, Outer apply works as Inner join , however ON condition is not required here... This is I know as the diff. b/w apply vs Joins.  But in real scenario like above, how to implement, That help actually i am looking. Appreciate your response & time!

Comment: Exact  doubt/ Questions: unable to understand below logic as how outer apply works and how this v(v) subset works? Also, Is there any other better solution there to achieve it?

Comment: The `APPLY` is being used to unpivot the data. The `v(vp)` are aliases of the resultset and column respectively for that unpivoted data (like `t` is the alias of the table `country_test2`).

Comment: Thanks @larnu for your reply. But The APPLY operator allows to join two table expressions; so, how's Apply operator being used to unpivot the data? And is there any other solution to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Because the `VALUES` table construct is defining one **row** per column. The alternative would be to use the clunky `UNPIVOT` operator

Comment: VALUES creates a fake table, one row for each of the columns passed to it.   APPLY does this for each row of the main table.  A DISTINCT Count is then done on all those fake columns for each row.

Comment: when I run the sample query on the sample data I get row-wise distinct counts not column-wise distinct counts (i.e., the result shows the number of distinct countries in the row).

Comment: I have not seen this syntax for naming a column: x(y) - is there a name for this? Is it a general feature in T-SQL? Or is it something specific to use of apply?

Comment: @topsail It's in the syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax `[ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]` it's allowed anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The logic is pretty simple once you understand how `APPLY` and `VALUES` work.

- Take each row of the original table

```sql
FROM country_test2 t
```

- "Apply" a rowset to *each* row. The *whole* `APPLY` is logically evaluated for each row of the previous table. Because of this, an `APPLY` subquery allows references to previous tables.

```sql
OUTER APPLY (
```

- Define a virtual table using the `VALUES` clause. Each row goes in `()` so there are four rows, each referring to a value from the outer `t` table

```sql
FROM (VALUES (t.c1),
             (t.c2),
             (t.c3),
             (t.c4)) v(vp)
```

- Get the distinct count within that `VALUES`. Because `COUNT()` is an aggregate, the final rowset is only one row, so this does not duplicate the outer `t` rows.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vp)
```

- Alias this subquery as `p` with a column `DistinctCount`

```sql
) p(DistinctCount);
```